# Trying to install a corpus for countVectorizer in sklearn package

Tags: corpus, countvectorizer

I am trying to load a corpus from my local drive into python at one time with a for loop and then read each text file and save it for analysis with countVectorizer. But, I am only getting the last file. How do I get the results from all of the files to be stored for analysis with countVectorizer?

This code brings out the text from last file in folder.

```
folder_path = "folder"

#import and read all files in animal_corpus
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        txt = f.read()
        print(txt)
MyList= [txt]

## Create a CountVectorizer object that you can use
MyCV1 = CountVectorizer()
## Call your MyCV1 on the data
DTM1 = MyCV1.fit_transform(MyList)
## get col names
ColNames=MyCV1.get_feature_names()
print(ColNames)

## convert DTM to DF

MyDF1 = pd.DataFrame(DTM1.toarray(), columns=ColNames)
print(MyDF1)
```

This code works, but would not work for a huge corpus that I am preparing it for.

```
#import and read text files 
f1 = open("folder/animal_1.txt",'r')
f1r = f1.read()
f2 = open("/folder/animal_2.txt",'r')
f2r = f2.read()
f3 = open("/folder/animal_3.txt",'r')
f3r = f3.read()

#reassemble corpus in python
MyCorpus=[f1r, f2r, f3r]

## Create a CountVectorizer object that you can use
MyCV1 = CountVectorizer()
## Call your MyCV1 on the data
DTM1 = MyCV1.fit_transform(MyCorpus)
## get col names
ColNames=MyCV1.get_feature_names()
print(ColNames)

## convert DTM to DF

MyDF2 = pd.DataFrame(DTM1.toarray(), columns=ColNames)
print(MyDF2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just gotta keep grinding.

```
MyCorpus=[]
#import and read all files in animal_corpus
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
        txt = f.read()
        MyCorpus.append(txt)
```